# How to receive the background notification in iOS 10?

Tags: push-notification, ios10, firebase-notifications

Description - Uptil iOS 9, following method gets called

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

But from iOS 10, apple provide new framework i.e userNotification.framework
and new methods to handle i.e

```
// The method will be called on the delegate only if the application is in the foreground. If the method is not implemented or the handler is not called in a timely manner then the notification will not be presented. The application can choose to have the notification presented as a sound, badge, alert and/or in the notification list. This decision should be based on whether the information in the notification is otherwise visible to the user.

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
```

and

```
// The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction. The delegate must be set before the application returns from applicationDidFinishLaunching:.

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

But Now I am not able to get the notification call back when app is in background and user not clicked on notification.

What I want is when user is in background and if he received any notification then in which method I will get the call back of received notification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS10, **willPresent** will be called when app is running foreground. **didReceive** will be called when user tap the notification while app is running background.

If you want handle notifications when app is running background, you still need to implement **didReceiveRemoteNotification...fetchCompletionHandler**, and don't forget to add **"content-available"** to your notification payload. Set it to 1.